# Where is this strange clock/painting located? (moving eyes)

Tags: identify-this, museums, locate-this, artworks

While I was browsing old pictures in my phone I found this one of a painting with a clock.
The eyes move at the same time as the hands of the clock.

But I don't remember where I took that picture.

Do you know where it is?

I have mixed pictures from four years ago and I've visited several countries in Europe since then.
Maybe it is in a small museum.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the EXIF data? Chances are there is GPS info in the original photo

Comment: @JanDvorak I've just checked but the GPS info is disabled.

Comment: @skan no, you just *undid* the corrections from Nate Eldredge.  Paint is the stuff you use to make a painting.  The picture in the question shows a painting.

Comment: Looks like a German blinking eye clock - like [this one](http://www.knottypineantiques.com/events/auctions_events_details.asp?AuctionID=5&LotNum=083)

Comment: Did you perhaps visit the Deutsches Uhrenmuseum in Furtwangen im Schwarzwald?

Comment: The blinking eye clock Is from the Black Forest, Germany, circa 1870.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed in Salamanca:

Antique In Exposición "La Medida Del Tiempo"

http://www.minube.sg/photos/place/160041/757851

Edit: Found a more up to date location via [this site](http://www.foroderelojes.es/showthread.php/51528-Exposicion-quot-la-medida-del-tiempo-quot-en-Salamanca) and can be seen on the left of [this photo](https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1531/24905664402_9b7094cb78_b.jpg):

[image: photo extract]

It's in a glass frame and there are clocks on the opposite wall which align with the picture from the question.

The page says it is now in the Fonseca palace.

Answer (score 2):

Because this clock was made in Germany in The Black forest, 1870,

The Only place I can think about is:

German Clock Museum

Robert-Gerwig-Platz 1, 78120 Furtwangen im Schwarzwald,

+49 7723 9202800

I think you can find your clock on this wall:
[Google View](https://www.google.co.il/maps/@48.0509186,8.2078753,3a,23y,140.63h,87.9t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s-ksZ3zDTWbqs%2FV-iLloaoULI%2FAAAAAAAABSI%2FtXKaqiHnaIcoj1duoP1QXAnNrPytdQffQCLIB!2e4!7i8000!8i4000)

Comment: That's nice, I love clocks and ancient machines. I've never been to Germany though.  
The numbering of this picture in my camera close to other taken in Salamanca, Spain.
Is it possible these clocks moved to other museums for a short time?

Comment: It does look like it belongs there, however there's a reflection of a clock on that painting which doesn't fit with anything facing that wall.